# Creating a image browser Boxee App

Tags: boxee

I am writing a Boxee App and I want to list all albums for a picasa account.

The problem I'm facing is that I have no idea of how to list albums and photos in the Boxee app.

The application itself should be fairly simple:
First a main screen where all your albums are listed, then when you click an album you see all your photos in a grid of say 4x5 photos
When you click a photo you go in to a view where one photo is displayed on the whole screen where back and forward lets users go back and forth in that gallery.

I have wrote a simple wrapper arround the gdata photos Python API which I was aiming to use so hopefully all the heavy lifting will be done by the gdata API.

Does anybody have some good links to example applications or tutorials to one or more of the features I want in the application?

Answer (score 2):

Boxee uses an XML based approach for describing an application's interface. You'll need one XML for each screen of your application and you'll connect them together using the API.

You would build this XML screens using various controls defined by the XML API. Basically a control (a button, a list, a label, etc) is described as an XML node with attributes and child nodes. You can check a list of all the available controls here: http://developer.boxee.tv/UI_Controls

You can use the Python API to control various properties of the UI elements you coded in your XML files. For example you could fill a list with photos taken from a server, you could change the label on a button, load another screen and much more. Here are the Python API specs: http://developer.boxee.tv/Python_API

Make sure you read trough the Boxee dev pages and also remember that Boxee originated from the XBMC project so most of the documentation regarding XBMC skinning (http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=Skinning_XBMC) also applies to Boxee.

Another thing that might help you is looking at other apps. Find an app that is somehow similar to what you want to do, find it in Boxee's app folder and peek at the code there.